# How do I stop Unity 7 from focusing a window when I scroll while hovering a launcher icon?

Tags: unity, launcher

If I hover the mouse pointer over a minimized (but running) application in the unity launcher and use my scroll wheel, the application will be un-minimized and put on top of all other applications.

Can i disable this behavior somehow?

Comment: Can you explain what you expected to happen instead?

Comment: @RobieBasak In Ubuntu Unity you can hover a launcher icon of a program , and scroll to make application windows take focus. OP wants to disable this behavior , i.e. they don't want windows appear if they use mouse or touchpad scroll. See my answer on how this can be done

Comment: The question &  question description are not the same. The setting mentioned below does not discriminate minimized vs. inactive (not focused). You should clean that up. (- there is no way to scroll only not minimized when at least one of each exist for an app (icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do so.

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager via `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Under `Desktop` click on `Ubuntu Unity  Plugin`
   [image]
3. Click on `Launcher` tab:

   [image]
4. Uncheck `Scroll Inactive Icon to Focus Application`
   [image]
5. Close the CompizConfig Settings Manager

That's it ! Changes take effect immediately.